# fade window on close

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, fade

How can I set time to run a for loop?

I'm going on fade a form on close and this is my code:

```
Time ftmr=new Timer();
//set time interval 5 sec
ftmr.Interval = 5000;
//starts the timer
ftmr.Start();
ftmr.Tick += Ftmr_Tick;

private void Ftmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        this.Opacity = 100 - i;
        this.Refresh();
    }
    Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Don't `Dispose` something you intend to use later.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong in your code. First, you shouldn't use a loop to set the `Opacity` since it will only really do something after the event is handled entirely. Let the timer do the looping. Second, don't `Dispose` your form in the timer. It will get rid of all UI elements, so you can throw your form away...

Try this:

```
Time ftmr=new Timer();
//set time interval 5 sec
ftmr.Interval = 5000 / 100; // 100 attempts
//starts the timer
ftmr.Start();
ftmr.Tick += Ftmr_Tick;

double opacity = 1;
private void Ftmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Opacity = opacity;
    opacity -= .01;
    this.Refresh();

    if (this.Opacity <= 0)
    {
        ftmr.Stop();
    }
}
```

Note that this code will take longer than 5 seconds to run due to the way the timer works. You might need to tweak the numbers a little bit.

Comment: But it doesn't fade the form.

Comment: That's it...
Thank YOU!

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the few cases where it is acceptable to hang the UI thread and use Thread.Sleep() instead.  The Opacity property is immediately effective and doesn't require a repaint.  Do so in the FormClosing event.

Be sure to start with the Opacity set to 0.99 so you don't get flicker from the native window getting re-created.  Five seconds is too long, both to the user and the operating system, about a second is reasonable.  For example:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Opacity = 0.99;
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        if (!e.Cancel) {
            for (int op = 99; op >= 0; op -= 3) {
                this.Opacity = op / 100f;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
            }
        }
    }
}
```